# Does nginx reload break existing HTTPS connections?

Tags: nginx

I want to recreate a certificate and to update nginx via reloading of the configuration using `nginx -s reload`.

Not clear if it will break existing HTTPS connections

According to the document
http://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html

> the master process starts new worker processes and sends messages to
> old worker processes, requesting them to shut down

Does `nginx -s reload` break existing HTTPS connections?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From same documentation (almost next sentence):

> Old worker processes, receiving a command to shut down, **stop accepting new connections** and **continue to service current requests** until all such requests are serviced. After that, the old worker processes exit.

So answer is no - `nginx -s reload` will not break already started request processing.